# How to Rotate TextView?

Tags: android

I want to rotate TextView but I can't get proper output. I am getting `textView` with missing some text

**In Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop = "50dip">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Shreeji \n Nath" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In Animation**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="40" android:toDegrees="-90" android:pivotX="40%"
        android:duration="0">
   </rotate>
```

**Java file**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.myanim);
    ranim.setFillAfter(true); 
    tv.setAnimation(ranim);

  }
}
```

Comment: Missing some text? if in first configuration - that means that your text is longer than 20dip which you set if the problem is during rotation, that's because your layout is too small to show 20dipx120dip

Comment: if I set wrap_content still problem is there

Comment: but your problem is during rotation?

Comment: yes exactly normally(without rotation there is no problem)

Comment: Strange. Your code works, there is no text missing. Only problem which I can see is that your animation:duration is 0 so in fact you cannot see animation. If you want to check the whole code - please provide it.

Comment: ok I am providing full code please check it

Comment: @ania let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1795/discussion-between-jignesh-ansodariya-and-ania)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the main.xml to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" android:id="@+id/text1"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeap, I agree with Mohit Verma, your animation works but you don't see your text because it's hidden. Change margins and you will see whole text. Second problem is what I mentioned previous - your animation is working but you cannot see effects because duration is 0, Change it to at least 1000 and you will see effects. And one more suggestion - in android tools you have tool called hierarchyviewer. You can check there many things about UI - it is very helpful and in this case would help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Added in API level 12

```
view.animate().rotationBy(90).start()
```