# How to rotate EditText manually in Android

Tags: android, custom-component

I have an image editing android application in which I am using a custom `EditTextView` which is placed on an `ImageView`.This image view is also a custom view which can rotate, zoom, drag, etc... Now, I want to drag this `EditText` and to rotate when click on a button. This is my custom `EditTextView`:

```
public class TemplateTextView extends EditText {
    private static float angle;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    private int mode = NONE;
    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    PointF startMargins = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    /**
     * Constructor for TemplateTextView
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public TemplateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // mWindowManager = (WindowManager)
        // context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for TemplateTextView
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public TemplateTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

    /**
     * Constructor for TemplateTextView
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public TemplateTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
}
```

The `EdittextView` is dragged when long click on it. How can I rotate and drag this view?

Comment: this question and answer will help you,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813367/how-to-rotate-textview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813367/how-to-rotate-textview

Answer (score 1):

For rotating, you can simply do that in the onDraw-Method of your TemplateTextView:

```
@Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.rotate(angle, canvas.getClipBounds().right/2, canvas.getClipBounds().bottom/2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
```

Cheers, Dude