# Rotate total Textview in -90 degrees

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I want to set my textview in -90 degrees means i haver to show it like this! i ahve to show 8 textviews in single linear layout. i am able to rotate but i can see only one textview.Please can any one help me with some example.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

```
public class AngledTextView extends TextView
{ 

       public AngledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
       { 
          super(context, attrs); 
       } 

       @Override 
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
       { // Save the current matrix 
         canvas.save(); 
         // Rotate this View at its center 
         canvas.rotate(270,this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight() /2); 
         // Draw it 
         super.onDraw(canvas); 
         // Restore to the previous matrix 
         canvas.restore(); 
        } 
 }
```

Comment: you should search here before asking,there are a lot of questions already answered [how to rotate text view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813367/how-to-rotate-textview) 
|
[how to rotate text 90 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959069/how-to-rotate-textview-90-degrees-and-display) 
|
[rotated label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android)

Comment: public class AngledTextView extends TextView {
 public AngledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // Save the current matrix
  canvas.save();
  // Rotate this View at its center
  canvas.rotate(270,this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight() /2);
  // Draw it
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  // Restore to the previous matrix
  canvas.restore();
 }
} i am using this code for textview.

Comment: where do you put it? Which kind of layout are you using?

Comment: i may think your problem lays inside your xml layout

Comment: i am using linear layout

Comment: why don't you put your phone in landscape ?

Comment: It is possible to do this in XML as of API 11 (Android 3.0). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774770/sideways-view-with-xml-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for a vertical TextView i used the following code and it worked perfectly.

```
public class VerticleTextView extends TextView {

final boolean topDown;
public VerticleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    final int gravity = getGravity();
    if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
       setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
       topDown = false;
    }else
       topDown = true;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
    textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

    canvas.save();

    if(topDown){
       canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
       canvas.rotate(90);
    }else {
       canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
       canvas.rotate(-90);
    }


    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());

    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
}
```

Comment: i need -90 degrees but it shows 90 degrees. when i changed it to -90 it wont show any result.

Comment: Thanks  @


Sam.Janz i got what i expect :)

Comment: if you really found this helpful then appreciate by accepting answer...:)

Comment: This only rotates the text. What about the background of the text? When I applied this code, it showed the text on top of not rotated background.

Answer (score 1):

you should use 270 instead of -90. this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Added in API level 12

```
    view.animate().rotationBy(90).start()
```