# Display the my text item horizontal as like below image

Tags: android

Display the my text item horizontal as like below image

please guide me to display my text item in the best way of design

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833891/rotate-total-textview-in-90-degrees

Comment: http://www.pocketmagic.net/2010/12/android-vertical-textview-custom-angle-text/#.U2mpwa2Sy1A

Comment: you can use `android:rotation="90"` for textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add property in Textview like below

```
android:rotation="90"
```